# Changing a method from converting just strings to strings and int

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, enums

Bear with me as this is a difficult concept for me. I have a method that returns the items in an `enum` as strings (for DB storage).  Here is the method:

```
public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetItemsFromEnum<T>
    (T selectedValue = default(T)) where T : struct
{
    return from name in Enum.GetNames(typeof(T))
       let enumValue = Convert.ToString((T)Enum.
           Parse(typeof(T), name, true))

           select new SelectListItem
           {
               Text = GetEnumDescription(name, typeof(T)),
               Value = enumValue,
               Selected = enumValue.Equals(selectedValue)
           };
}
```

(NB: `GetEnumDescription` is another method in the class that gets the `[Display(Name="")` text to display something friendly in the UI.)

For a single select input (radio button, drop down), this works great. However, with multi-selects (list box, check box list), I am thinking of using the `enum` `[Flags]` attribute to store in the DB as an `int`.

However, the `GetItemsFromEnum` method will not work in the case that I use `[Flags]` and requires that I change it so that the value assigned in the `GetItemsFromEnum` method isn't the string value of the `enum`, it's the `int` value.

This is actually a two-parter:

1. How can I modify the method so that `enumValue` would be the
   value of the `int` from `enum` `[Flags]` (i.e., if "1 + 2" were selected
   (two check boxes), then the `int` value saved would be "3")?
2. Most importantly, what kind of logic can I insert in the method
   so that all my other `enum`'s (those without `[Flags]`) are not
   affected (i.e., it still converts `ToString`)? I was thinking some `if ... else` logic, but would that work?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the `[Flags]` attribute doesn't add special properties to the enum's values, it's just used through Reflection by the `Enum` class when formatting it as a string and to let people who use your code know that they can use bitwise operations on the enum safely, or in other words, without undesired results.

Let's take this enum:

```
[Flags]
enum MyEnum
{
    Undefined,
    Employee,
    Student
}
```

And let's create a variable this way:

```
var employeeAndStudent = MyEnum.Employee | MyEnum.Student;
```

The variable, if cast to integer, is equals to 3. While the `ToString()` method will print "Employee, Student", `Enum.GetNames` doesn't have a value assigned for the field 3 -- Quite obviously, since it has no *name*. I can think of two solutions:

1. You create your own `GetNames` which will return, in addition to the defined names, also all the possible combinations of the enum's values, conveniently printed in your format.
2. You define the flags in the enum, which can become pretty wasteful if there are many members. In our case, `MyEnum` would become:

   ```
   [Flags]
   enum MyEnum
   {
       Undefined,
       Employee,
       Student,
       EmployeeAndStudent
   }
   ```

One more thing, your method seems to have a bug. This line:

```
Selected = enumValue.Equals(selectedValue)
```

Is trying to compare an enum type to a string, and will always result in false. Are you sure that `SelectListItem.Value` should be of type `string`? I suggest you to review your code.

To give direct answers to your question:

1. Add `[Flags]` to your enum and use the OR operator to combine values.
2. In your `GetEnumDescription` method, check if the type has the `Flags` attribute.

Comment: In your example, without Flags attribute employeeAndStudent.ToString() would return "3". It might change the enum behavior!

Comment: @knaki02 You're right, I should've been more specific, I'll edit my post.

Comment: Thank you for the tips, but I get myself confused with Flags. Why create variables with combinations? I thought the whole point of Flags, was (assuming 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64) to get one integer value of, for example, 106 (which means 2, 8, 32, and 64 were selected).

Comment: @MEMoriarty Because in your case you call `Enum.GetNames`, which doesn't return names for possible (but not defined) combinations of your fields. If you had an enum with just 32 fields, your method would return over 4 billion strings!